# Chrome Extension - Duplication of the event listener?

Tags: event-handling, google-chrome-extension

**Introduction**

I've got a problem with my extension for Chrome. It supposed to show a small overlay popup window (created in jQuery) with search results from google based on your text selection. Basically you should be able to highlight a text on any page, right click on it (context menu), click on "Search for 'selected keyword'" and a small window pops up in the same tab as an overlay with all search results from google or different search engine.

**The problem**

Now the extension works really well and without problems, HOWEVER after extensive using of this extension (let's say 1 hour) when I'll highlight another keyword and search for it, extension REMEMBERS last keyword and shows wrong search results. Then again, when I'll highlight another keywords it rememebrs the keyword I've just highlighted but previously didn't get the results for it. It's like a chaining process and I'm always one keyword behind.

**My thoughts**

I think that the cause of this problem might be event listeners, because when this problem occurs I've got a log from console.log(chrome.extension.onRequest.hasListeners()); which says true. It means that there are 2 or more event listeners attached and they shouldn't as I'm removing them by chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener(listener1);

Maybe it happens when the actual web page is still loading and I'm highlighting keyword, clicking on context menu and extension can't load yet but somehow event listeners firing... I really can't fully replicate this problem... and what causes this problem.

**Manifest File**

```
{
  "name": "Search Accelerator",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Search Accelerator extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon19.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["content_script.js"]
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "18",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "management",
    "webRequest"
  ]
}
```

**Content Script**

> chrome.contextMenus.create({      "title": 'Search for "%s"',
>     "contexts":['selection'],       "onclick": getClickHandler() });
>
> function getClickHandler() {   return function(info, tab) {
>   console.log(chrome.extension.onRequest.hasListeners());
>
> ```
> chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function listener1 (request, sender, sendResponse) {
>   var url = "http://www.google.com/?s=" + info.selectionText;
>   console.log(url);       var keywordObj = {keyword: url};
>   if (request.keywordRequest == "Yes") {
>     console.log(keywordObj);
>     sendResponse(keywordObj);
>   };
>   chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener(listener1);     }     );
>
> chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
> chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "popup.js" });
> });   }; };
> ```

**Popup js**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({keywordRequest: "Yes"}, function(response) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#e14_accelerator")) {
        $("#e14_accelerator").remove();
    }
    var rkeyword = response.keyword;

    $("body").append("<div id=\"e14_accelerator\" style=\"position: fixed;top: 30px;right: -330px;z-index: 999999; \"><iframe style=\"border:5px solid #c9c9c9;-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);\" src=\""+ rkeyword +"\" width=\"328\" height=\"240\"></iframe></div>");
    $("#e14_accelerator").animate({right:-13},500);

    $(document).click(function() {
            $("#e14_accelerator").remove();
    });
    $("#e14_accelerator").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
 });
});
```

**Error messages that appear when this problem occur:**

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html?docked=true&dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(230,230,230,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host. sendRequest:21
chromeHidden.handleResponse sendRequest:21
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html?docked=true&dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(230,230,230,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host. sendRequest:21
chromeHidden.handleResponse
```

Comment: Why are you adding and removing a listner every time they click on something?  Why not just declare the listner outside that function and leave it there?

Comment: @PAEZ because when I'll not remove it, chrome tries to add it again and says that it can't assign more than one listeners.

Comment: What I also found this morning when I left Chrome opened over night, that it happened again, and threw two error messages: Error during tabs.executeScript. More details at the bottom of my main post. And after that again I was one keyword behind. It almost look like there's some kind of session expire time. Please help :(